# set the callout annotation title from "DidSelectAnnotationView" in Swift 2.0 and Data From CoreData

Tags: swift, core-data, annotations, mapkit

please help. =) i have a problem to set the callout title. I receive the informations from core data with predicates. 
When i click on a annotation on the map, i receive all data from the pin in my Logs.

how can set the title in the callout Bubble?

```
  func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {

  let annotationView:MKPinAnnotationView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "CheckpointPins")

 if annotation is MKUserLocation {
     return nil }
  else {

        let pred:NSPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "checkpoint_longitude != nil && checkpoint_latitude != nil")
        let items = fetchedResultsController?.fetchedObjects
        let filt = (items! as NSArray).filteredArrayUsingPredicate(pred)

        let startCheckPoint:Checkpoint = (filt as NSArray).firstObject as! Checkpoint!
        let endCheckpoint:Checkpoint = (filt as NSArray).lastObject as! Checkpoint!

        if filt.count != 0 {

           if startCheckPoint .isEqual(annotation) {
              annotationView.pinTintColor = MKPinAnnotationView.greenPinColor()
           }else if endCheckpoint.isEqual(annotation) {

              annotationView.pinTintColor = MKPinAnnotationView.purplePinColor()
           }else {
              annotationView.pinTintColor = MKPinAnnotationView.redPinColor()

           }
     }
           let point = annotation as! Checkpoint

           annotationView.tag = (point.checkpoint_order?.integerValue)!
           annotationView.enabled = true
           annotationView.animatesDrop = true
   //  annotationView.canShowCallout = true
   annotationView.annotation = annotation
           // annotationView.opaque = false
           print("tag = \(annotationView.tag)")
  }
  return annotationView
 }

 func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, didSelectAnnotationView view: MKAnnotationView) {

  if !(view.annotation!.isKindOfClass(MKUserLocation)) {

     let pred:NSPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "checkpoint_longitude != nil && checkpoint_latitude != nil")
     let pred2:NSPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "checkpoint_order == %d", view.tag)
     let compoundPredicate:NSPredicate = NSCompoundPredicate(andPredicateWithSubpredicates: [pred, pred2])

     let items = fetchedResultsController?.fetchedObjects
     let filt = (items! as NSArray).filteredArrayUsingPredicate(compoundPredicate)
     let point:Checkpoint = (filt as NSArray).firstObject as! Checkpoint

     print(point.description)

        }

  }
 }
```

Comment: Why is `annotationView.canShowCallout = true` commented out?

Comment: when i set this to true, it crashed. see log: must implement title when canShowCallout is YES on corresponding view <MKPinAnnotationView: 0x7fb9ef536e70; frame = (-16 -19.5; 32 39); layer = <MKLayer: 0x7fb9ef537140>> visible:1 +48.40999985, +16.19169998'

Answer (score 2):

First of all, if you want to show callouts, you need to set `canShowCallout` to `true`. There are no callouts unless you enable them.

In a comment you said that you're getting a crash with an error that reads `must implement title when canShowCallout is YES on corresponding view <MKPinAnnotationView: 0x7fb9ef536e70...` What this is telling you is that the object you used as your annotation does not implement the `title` part of the `MKAnnotation` protocol. The `title` is an optional part of the protocol **unless you use callouts** in which case you must implement it. The title is what's displayed on the callout. The error message is telling you that you enabled the callout but didn't provide a title to display. You can either add `title` to the class you're using as the `MKAnnotation` or you can skip using callouts.

Comment: ok thanks for your help TOM. i added a custom view when i pressed the annotation, so i get all data what i need ;) i added a UILabel, my Code yet:  annotationPlace.text = point.checkpoint_name!